# How to integrate Google authentication with Devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm setting up a rails app with both normal signup and google authentication combined. For normal Signup, I will use Devise gem and I want to integrate an optional google login. How do I integrate Devise Authentication and Google Authentication properly?

For my rails applications, I have implemented Google authentication alone successfully and I have also implemented Devise Authentication successfully. But I don't know how to combine both together with a single "User" table for user records.

The expected login is this:

https://prnt.sc/m004wf

Comment: Trying to combine identity providers is an entire product by itself. I would use an existing provider such as Auth0 or Okta. There are many to choose from. They also have extensive libraries to make your integration effort very easy.

Comment: @JohnHanley auth0 and okta are paid services, right? Would you suggest some free ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [omniauth-oauth2](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-oauth2) and [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2).
Implementation is provided in it.
For facebook login, you can use, [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook)

Also you have to create project on [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com) to use google plus authentication where you can get oauth client id & secret key, which will be used in your application.

Comment: @AbhiRavi Try [ref-1](https://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails) & [ref-2](https://medium.com/@ajayramesh/social-login-with-omniauth-and-rails-5-0-ad2bbd2a998e)

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely give it a try and put my feedback here soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do that, using the [devise_two_factor](https://github.com/tinfoil/devise-two-factor) gem.